# Restore mysql to any specific time of past?

Tags: mysql

Last week, one of our developers ran a update query on the production mysql master `update xxx set yyy=zzz`, without **where**. We backup the mysql everyday 00:01, and he did this on 17:xx, is there any way to restore the database to any specific time of past? Apparently we cannot take snapshot every seconds.

Recover procedure:

1. Restore the mysql to backup, say 2017-06-11 00:01:00
2. mysqlbinlog binglog* to text file queries.sql
3. remove queries before 2017-06-11 00:01:00
4. remove queries after `update xxx set yyy=zzz`
5. mysql < queries.sql

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to restore from the previous backup. You can only `ROLLBACK` during a transaction i.e. if you start with a `BEGIN;` you can do changes and then either confirm them with a `COMMIT;` on undo with a `ROLLBACK;`. There's no other undo history than that.

There shouldn't be need for backups for every second, but if there is a risk these could happen again, you could consider more frequent sqldumps – or not letting developers play with the production database.

If you had [binary log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html) enabled, you could **redo**, rather than undo, all the modifications made after the backup. As the binary log only stores queries, not the data, this has to be done starting from the backup, not from the current state. If the mistake happened last week, this might not be an option now, but good to at least enable for the future.

The mistake being `update xxx set yyy=zzz;` you only got one column with false data. Depending on the column and how much other tables are depending on that data you could prevent restoring the whole database to a previous state from the last backup. If you were lucky, you could be able to take only this particular table from the dump and modify the `INSERT` queries to `UPDATE` queries for the single column.

Comment: What about binary log? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

Comment: Thank you, I updated recover procedure by binary log, could you please review?

Comment: That would do literally what's in the title. However, "remove queries after" is most likely something you don't want to do as you will lose modifications after the accident. It should be sufficient to remove just the single bad query.

Comment: I'd add your recover procedure as an answer to your own question. Inside the question it's a bit confusing.